# How to keep null values when writing to csv using opencsv

Tags: java, spring-boot, opencsv

I am using opencsv with java but i am not able to keep null while generating csv it always convert null to empty string.
Please suggest if its possible, Here is my code .

```
    Writer writer = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
    StatefulBeanToCsv<?> sbc = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<?>(writer)
            .withMappingStrategy(mappingStrategy)
            .withSeparator(CSVWriter.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR)
            .withQuotechar(CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER)
            .withEscapechar(CSVWriter.DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER)
            .withLineEnd(CSVWriter.DEFAULT_LINE_END)
            .withOrderedResults(false)
            .build();
```

Comment: When you say 'keep' null values, what is it that you want to see in your csv?

Comment: you can use .withApplyQuotesToAll(false) if you dont want empty String .

Comment: @VishakhaLall i want to see null in my csv instead of empty

Comment: @MandarDharurkar i tried .withApplyQuotesToAll(false) but it is giving result as ,, whereas with .withApplyQuotesToAll(true) it gives " ". everytime it is considering null as empty string only

Comment: Do you want it to have the string 'null'?

Comment: yes i think that will also help

Comment: I'm sorry, you're not being clear. Can you tell us exactly what you're looking for as the null value, null in java is a pointer to empty address, in csv there's no such concept and will therefore be an empty string. What are you looking for other than 'null' in the cell?

Comment: @rishabh, adding "null" will make it irrelevant in csv file . are you sure you want it as null?

Comment: i agree with @VishakhaLall

Comment: yeah i understand  in csv there's no such concept of null and therefore it treat as  empty string but i have a requirement that if i am getting null value from the db it should show null in csv too

Comment: Can you share the Class/format of data before it is written to the csv?

Comment: please look at the json i am converting to csv : {"accessDateTime": "2020-01-14T10:04:54 UTC","userId": "SA:10001","name": "Rishabh","username": "rishabh.sharma@gmail.com","userRole":"[SUPERADMIN]","message": "Started a new session ","action": "SESSION","voucherId": null,"currencyType": null,"value": 0.0,"currentValue": 0.0,"adjustedValue": 0.0,"customerId": null,"customerEmail": null,"partnerId": null,"partnerName": null,"newUserId": null,"newUserEmail": null,"newUserRole": null,"environment": "localhost"}

Comment: this is the response i am getting after converting to csv :2020-01-14T10:04:54,SA:10001,Rishabh,rishabh.sharma@gamil.com,[SUPERADMIN],Started a new session ,SESSION,,,0.0,0.0,0.0,,,,,,,,localhost

Comment: instead of empty space (,,,) i need null value as (,null,null,)

Answer (score 0):

While it's not the most realistic approach, since you specifically require the word 'null' to instead of the empty string, you might want to change the same in the JSON itself. 
 Here's what you could do, parse the JSON, and if the value in the (key,value) pair is null, modify the value to "null".